# Junit Test test for jdbcTemplateOracle.queryForObject

Tags: java

How to write junit for below line.

jdbcTemplateOracle.queryForObject(checkExistingCommentQuery, sqlParam, Integer.class)

Here checkExistingCommentQuery is a "String" and
sqlParam is a "Map<String, Object>" type

Answer (score 0):

It can be tested by directly running the queries on the database and evaluating on actual result. Also you can do the test by `Mock` as well.
The below example is a way to write the test using `Mock`

You need to mock your `JdbcTemplate` object so that it don't run the SQL statement on a database.

```
@Mock
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Test
public void testJDBCTemplateResult(){
   //set the above mock template in the class which is using it.

   Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(checkExistingCommentQuery, sqlParam, Integer.class)).thenReturn(//expected Result);

   assertEquals(//to check your results);
}
```